# Passing parameters from Badge to Adobe AIR App on update doesn't work

Tags: apache-flex, air

i've implemented a badge (based on the original one) passing parameters from HTML/JS to my AIR-app. Everything works fine when I install or launch my application. But if I try to update my application using the badge my parameters get lost. Instead I only retrieve the path to the downloaded AIR-File, which will be used as update.

Has anybody ever run into such problems? Is this an Adobe Bug or am I overlooking something?

Some more information:
I put a breakpoint right into that line of code where the badge calls the app. There the parameters are correct. I also log the arguments of the InvocationEvent in the application directly in my eventlistener. There the parameters are missing. What can I do?

Comment: Just a comment... I observe the same behavior passing arguments from the command line to launch an Air application. Everything works fine until the application updates itself upon launching (in which case the arguments get lost). This must be an oversight, as I can't see how it can be intended.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be intended behaviour by Adobe.

I found this statement on http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/InvokeEvent.html#arguments :

"Note: When multiple files are selected and opened on Mac® OS X, AIR dispatches a single invoke event containing the names of all the selected files in the arguments array. On Windows® and Linux, however, AIR dispatches a separate invoke event for each selected file containing only that filename in the arguments array."

That's probably what i see in my app - my badge parameters get ignored and the filename is the only parameter i get.